# AVERAGE calculation from multiple sheets, scattered vast data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

can someone advise how to calculate AVERAGE for certain reference, from multiple sheets, data is scattered in random row per each sheet.

Columns are same in all sheets, but rows differ in some as data is more vast.

For example: sheet1, reference which i need to calculate average for is in cell D2, but in cell J2 in sheet5, and in cell M2 in sheet 10 .. etc.

Thank You!

Comment: Is there any other column which could designate the values you want to average, like a date or an ID No.?

Comment: Hello, I can say yes. But let me clarify how the data is presented.

Presumably, name is column A, ID is column B - which i can use a unique reference in all worksheets. 
My desired AVERAGE is for column H representing sales volume for example, and data spread per column is unified in all sheets.

Hope this is helpful insight.

Comment: Is there any way to identify **which rows** in column H are supposed to be averaged?

Comment: All! from row 2 till 25 :)

Comment: If the number of sheets is not too large, just type =AVERAGE(  in the cell where you want the average.  Then go to each sheet and drag your mouse through each of the ranges that you want to average. Type ) to end the formula.  Excel will format the range references properly.  Is that something you could do?

Comment: If the ranges aren't continuous, you can click on each cell and enter a comma (,) after it.

Comment: I'm afraid this wont help, as it will lead to huge manual selections that I'm trying to manipulate with composite formula. I had to do a SUM for other values which I used SUM PRODUCT, SUMIF & INDIRECT formulas for.

I can't formulate AVERAGE for the same though :(

Comment: @Ahmad - Yes you can. First you designate one cell per sheet which will work like a pointer to the randow row. It can work for a random column too. As long as you keep this "pointer" cell static across sheets it can help you a lot in future. So let me assume you can do this much. Now use "Indirect()" function to "construct" a cell reference. "Indirect()" is the clever technique here. Thats it!

Comment: There is an AVERAGEIF() function...